# isKeyDown not working in Java

Tags: java, image, input

I am just playing around with some java programming and so I wanted a picture to move around the screen when I press a key. How ever I get a message saying "Thu Jun 14 13:14:23 EDT 2012 INFO:Controllers not available" this is the code I have for this page

```
public class Menu extends BasicGameState
{
    Image sun;
    int sunX = 200;
    int sunY = 200;

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException
    {
        sun = new Image("res/sun.png");
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException
    {
        g.drawImage(sun, sunX, sunY);
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException
    {
        Input input = gc.getInput();
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)); {sunY -= 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)); {sunY += 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)); {sunX -= 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)); {sunX += 1;}
    }
}
```

Right now if I was to run it like that the object will say in the same spot, but if I only have one of if statements object will move int the direction with out me pressing a key so if I have `if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)); {sunY -= 1;}` as soon as the app starts the sun moves up and off the screen. What have I done wrong for this to happen?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing this 
   `if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)); {sunY -= 1;}` 
to this :D

```
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {sunY -= 1;}
```

Comment: @MichaelZeuner In other words, remove the semicolons after your if statements. The semicolon after the if statement is an empty statement that is being executed instead of the line `{sunY -=1;}`